# Facebook iOS app sometimes not switching back to my app after authorization

Tags: facebook, authorization, unity-game-engine, switching

I'm creating an app that has facebook integration to post images to a user's wall.

I'm using the prime31 unity plugin called 'Social Networking'.

Here's my issue: on a fresh run (having no previous authorizations on Facebook and having uninstalled the app on the device to make sure there is no cached data), I'll login to facebook with "email" as the only permission. The device then switches from my app to the facebook app to ask the user for permission. I hit the 'log in' button, then MOST of the time I'll just end up switching to my news feed in facebook without ever switching back to my app. Sometimes after switching to the facebook app instead of the permission screen I'll end up on a blank page with 'cancel' as the only button up top, and pressing 'cancel' does nothing (I'm stuck on that blank page). And sometimes I'll authorize and correctly switch back to my app.

EDIT:
Well this feels pointless, but I discovered the source of the problem so I thought I would share in case anyone else runs into this.

My problem was that when I was building from Unity, I was usually hitting cmd-B (or build/append). This overwrites the info.plist file, removing the URL injection that the prime31 plugin does for the app switch.

Going into the build settings menu, hitting 'build and run', and pressing 'replace' will run the code that inserts the URL into info.plist.

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.